# Testando conexão servidor web - Android

Tags: android, conexão

Estou precisando fazer um teste de conexão com o servidor web, estou utilizando esse código abaixo porem todas as tentativas que efectuei ele sempre caiem no **catch**

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {

                URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                if (conn.getResponseCode() == conn.HTTP_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexao ok" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return  false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexao Problema", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return  false;
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha:" + e.getMessage()  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return  false;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnect"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: No catch qual é a mensagem que ele retorna?

Answer (score 3):

Use o [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring?hl=pt-br) para verificar se há realmente uma conexão à Internet e, se houver, qual é o tipo de conexão existente.

**Determinar se há uma conexão à Internet**

Não há necessidade de agendar uma atualização com base em um recurso da Internet se não houver uma conexão à Internet. O snippet a seguir mostra como usar o ConnectivityManager para consultar a rede ativa e determinar se ela tem conectividade com a internet.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
return isConnected;
}
```

Agora, valide se há conexão antes de executar alguma instrução.

```
if(isOnline(mContext)) {
   //restante do seu código
}
```

Comment: O que isso faz? Seria interessante complementar sua resposta com alguma explicação... ;)

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta com mais detalhes. Obrigado pelo toque

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza!?

Você poderá usar a seguinte função:

```
public boolean isOnline() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        String command = "ping -c 1 google.com";
        return (Runtime.getRuntime().exec (command).waitFor() == 0);
    }
```

Substitua o google pela URL do seu servidor.